# How to trigger a download in browser from a Firebase Function for an image in GCS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm using this Firebase Cloud Function so that my users can download images from GCS instead of viewing them in the browser.

The problem is that for some reason, some images are still displayed in the browser.

Is there anything I'm missing?

```
const request = require('request');
const mime = require('mime-types');

exports.downloadFile = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    const url = req.query.url;
    const filename = url.split('/').pop();
    const mimetype = mime.lookup(filename);

    const headers = {
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=' + filename,
        'Content-type': mimetype
    };

    res.set(headers);

    request(url).pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Note that if you do it this way, you're paying double egress costs.  Once for Cloud Storage, and another for Cloud Functions.

Comment: I'm aware of this. If you have a better solution, I'm all ears.

Comment: That download tag in the answer looks promising!

Comment: Doesn't work as it's not the same domain...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting content type to `application/octet-stream` instead of the one you are loading from a file.

[RFC2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046) specification of mime types describes `application/octet-stream` as *arbitrary binary data*. It is supported in all major browsers

Additionally, your href tags may use [a "download" tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp).

**Edit:**
Some browsers tend to detect mime type from a file's header. To prevent mime type detection and force download, beside modifying content type you also have to add `Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary`  header.

Comment: I've set the content type to `application/octet-stream` but for some reason, for some files, these are still shown in the browser instead of downloaded. I will try the `download` property.

Comment: Same result with the `download` property. According to the docs it has to be the same domain: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: let's try adding additional header: `Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary`

Comment: That did it, for some files at least. Please update your answer. I have another issue which I will post in a new question.

Comment: It should also be noted that this can only be done with files that are less than 10MB since that is the max size of the HTTP request with cloud functions. https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#resource_limits